# forcing an activity to do something when a variable value changes

Tags: android

I'm developing an android application. In my project I've created a class for handling something a (handler). I call a function defined in the handler from an activity. is there a way to force the activity to do something when a certain string value changes in the handler?

Comment: Did you check the [Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)?

Comment: If you are the one controlling the change of the string, besides Observer pattern, you can just use a callback to the activity

Comment: How does the Activity communicate with the Handler?

Comment: In the activity, i make a new object instance of the handler class